# How to display PowerShell Results in Textboxes

Tags: c#, powershell

I am brand new to C# and am trying to run the following code into a button's click event.

```
using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShell.AddScript("Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object CsDNSHostName,WindowsProductName, OSVersion, CSDomainRole, CSProcessors, OsProductType");
            powerShell.AddCommand("Out-String");


            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powerShell.Invoke();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject pSObject in PSOutput)
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());
            Tab2TxtBox2.Text = stringBuilder.ToString(); }
```

I will not be using Get-Computerinfo in my final script, I'm just using that commandlet to learn what I need to know. I will be using Get-AdComputer in my actual program. In this example I want to display   CsDNSHostName,WindowsProductName, OSVersion, CSDomainRole, CSProcessors, and OsProductType in whichever textbox I want (I have six total boxes). I can display one item by using this code but don't know how to get the other items to display,

```
powerShell.AddScript("Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object CsDNSHostName -expand CsDNSHostName -unique);
```

I hope someone here can help me.Thanks to anyone that is able to help.

Comment: You already defined a textbox (`Tab2TxtBox2`), and assigned it some text (`Tab2TxtBox2.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();`).  In your question it is unclear why you cannot create another textbox (like, i.e.: `Textbox3`), and assign it some text, like: `Textbox3.Text = 'Hello World!';`.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. I want to know how to get CsDNSHostName,WindowsProductName, OSVersion, CSDomainRole, CSProcessors, and OsProductType from Get-ComputerInfo and then display each one in a textbox. I know to display just one, but not all of them. I can send you a screenshot of my app if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split your string into an array or list and then assign them to the textboxes.

```
            using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powerShell.AddScript("Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object CsDNSHostName,WindowsProductName, OSVersion, CSDomainRole, CSProcessors, OsProductType");
                powerShell.AddCommand("Out-String");
                Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powerShell.Invoke();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (PSObject pSObject in PSOutput)
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());
                var stringarr = stringBuilder.ToString().Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                textBox1.Text = stringarr[0];
                textBox2.Text = stringarr[1];
                textBox3.Text = stringarr[2];
                textBox4.Text = stringarr[3];
                textBox5.Text = stringarr[4];
                textBox6.Text = stringarr[5];
            }
```

One quite note you might like for future usage.
If you add/change ConvertTo-Json + Newtonsoft.Json to your project you can easily phrase the string output (JSON Formated) to a class.

1. Change Out-String to ConvertTo-Json

```
powerShell.AddCommand("ConvertTo-Json");
```

2. Stop in debug once after Clipboard.SetText(stringBuilder.ToString());
3. Use Visual Studio Menu -> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes

Full code to phrase your output to a class.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powerShell.AddScript("Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object CsDNSHostName,WindowsProductName, OSVersion, CSDomainRole, CSProcessors, OsProductType");
                powerShell.AddCommand("ConvertTo-Json");
                Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powerShell.Invoke();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (PSObject pSObject in PSOutput)
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());
                }
#if DEBUG
                Clipboard.SetText(stringBuilder.ToString());
#endif
                Rootobject retval = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(stringBuilder.ToString());

                textBox1.Text = retval.CsDNSHostName.Trim();
                textBox2.Text = retval.WindowsProductName.Trim();
                textBox3.Text = retval.OsVersion.Trim();
                textBox4.Text = retval.CsDomainRole.ToString();
                textBox5.Text = retval.CsProcessors[0].Description.Trim();
                textBox6.Text = retval.OsProductType.ToString();
            }
        }


        public class Rootobject
        {
            public string CsDNSHostName { get; set; }
            public string WindowsProductName { get; set; }
            public string OsVersion { get; set; }
            public int CsDomainRole { get; set; }
            public Csprocessor[] CsProcessors { get; set; }
            public int OsProductType { get; set; }
        }

        public class Csprocessor
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public int Architecture { get; set; }
            public int AddressWidth { get; set; }
            public int DataWidth { get; set; }
            public int MaxClockSpeed { get; set; }
            public int CurrentClockSpeed { get; set; }
            public int NumberOfCores { get; set; }
            public int NumberOfLogicalProcessors { get; set; }
            public object ProcessorID { get; set; }
            public object SocketDesignation { get; set; }
            public object ProcessorType { get; set; }
            public string Role { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public int CpuStatus { get; set; }
            public int Availability { get; set; }
        }
```

I usually use this methode to invoke a script.

```
public List<object> InvokeScript(string script)
        {

            List<object> pSDataStreams = new List<object>();
            using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powerShell.Streams.Information.DataAdding += (sender, e) => { pSDataStreams.Add(e.ItemAdded); };
                powerShell.Streams.Error.DataAdding += (sender, e) => { pSDataStreams.Add(e.ItemAdded); };
                powerShell.Streams.Debug.DataAdding += (sender, e) => { pSDataStreams.Add(e.ItemAdded); };
                powerShell.Streams.Progress.DataAdding += (sender, e) => { pSDataStreams.Add(e.ItemAdded); };
                powerShell.Streams.Verbose.DataAdding += (sender, e) => { pSDataStreams.Add(e.ItemAdded); };
                powerShell.Streams.Warning.DataAdding += (sender, e) => { pSDataStreams.Add(e.ItemAdded); };

                powerShell.AddScript(script);

                // powerShell.Streams.Information.d
                using (var outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>())
                {
                    outputCollection.DataAdding += (sender, e) => { pSDataStreams.Add(e.ItemAdded); };
                    powerShell.Invoke(null, outputCollection);
                }
            }
            return pSDataStreams;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much Naitwatch! This worked really well but the output was unexpected. When I run what you provided, I get the following,

Comment: CsDNSHostName      : LAPTOP-NAME
WindowsProductName : Windows 10 Enterprise
OsVersion          : 10.0.19044
CsDomainRole       :  0
CsProcessors       : Intel64 Family 6 Model 140 Stepping 1
OsProductType      : 1

Comment: I should be getting this according to the output I get in PowerShell, 

CsDNSHostName      : LAPTOP-NAME
WindowsProductName : Windows 10 Pro
OsVersion          : 10.0.19044
CsDomainRole       : StandaloneWorkstation
CsProcessors       : {11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz}
OsProductType      : WorkStation

Comment: Also, as I mentioned earlier, I will be using Get-AdComputer for my app, and I need for the computer name that I look up to be entered through one of my textboxes. So, in the add script part it'll be something like Get-AdComputer (Input from textbox1) Select-Object CsDNSHostName,WindowsProductName, OSVersion, CSDomainRole, CSProcessors, OsProductType") Thanks for your patience as I am just learning c#. I've been doing PowerShell for a while and find it so easy in comparison lol. It's also been difficult to find people that want to help me.

Comment: Just use this string notation: var cn = "computername"; var ps = $@"Get-ADComputer -Identity ""{cn}"" -Properties *"; Please don't forget to upvote or accept answers if there somewhat usefull.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers! One final thing if you don't mind. I have this if statement in my click event so that if the box is empty, it will display a message in my status bar and then wait for the next command. 

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Tab2TxtBox1.Text))
{ this.StatusText.Text = "Must Enter Valid Computer Name!"; return; }

I don't know if this is the best way to do this in C#, but it works. I want another if statement that will display another message if an invalid entry is written in the textbox or if the computer name isn't found. I tried several things, but it didn't work.

Comment: Also, any idea about the discrepancy in the data returned in c# versus what I get when I run the script in powershell? In C# I get, 

CsDNSHostName : LAPTOP-NAME
WindowsProductName : Windows 10 Enterprise 
OsVersion : 10.0.19044 
CsDomainRole : 0 
CsProcessors : Intel64 Family 6 Model 140 Stepping 1 
OsProductType : 1 – 
 
In Powershell I get, 

CsDNSHostName : LAPTOP-NAME 
WindowsProductName : Windows 10 Pro 
OsVersion : 10.0.19044 
CsDomainRole : StandaloneWorkstation 
CsProcessors : {11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz}
OsProductType : WorkStation

Comment: If there differences in the class check the underlying .net version of the powershell version used.

Comment: Thanks Carsten! How do I stop the script if there is invalid entry in my Textbox ? So for example, if Get-Adcomputer in powershell returns that the computer name entered doesn't exist, how do I make the script not break? As I mentioned above,

 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Tab2TxtBox1.Text)) { this.StatusText.Text = "Must Enter Valid Computer Name!"; return; }

 works if the textbox is empty. Again, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Edited the answer, you need to get powerShell.Streams.Error.DataAdding events. Use my method in a debug/view, phrase the content of the List<object>

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2 especially -ErrorAction if you want to manipulate error behavior on the script level

Comment: Thanks @Carsten.R again for all your help. Everything on the page that I'm working on is working thanks to your help, but I am having one last issue with the data returned. The PwdLastSet does not display in a readable format. I tried using,  long Password = "pwdLastSet"[0]; DateTime pwdlastset = DateTime.FromFileTime((long)Password); TxtBox6.Text = pwdlastset.ToString(); and got 12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM in the textbox. It should read 8/30/2022 7:00:10 PM. I've searched high and low and have not found a solution. Can you help me?

Comment: I need to see the PowerShell part for this (and a description of the environment), if it is not suitable to post it here, please open a new question. I guess it is active directory, have you check manually if the active directory has the correct data (Displayed in a system Gui)